# Writing a where clause query

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm trying to create a query that will show the properties that were sold and were on the market for less than 6 weeks. In the listings table, there is BeginListDate and EndList Date.

```
So far my WHERE statement looks like
WHERE SaleStatus.Salestatus = 'Sold' AND DATEDIFF(YEAR,BeginListDate, EndListDate) >42
```

but that query is incorrect. I'm just confused on how to write a where statement where it only considers those that were on the market for less than 6 weeks.

Comment: This is a great place to start: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx Have a look at the datepart argument.  Specifically `day`.

Comment: Datediff(day,BeginListDate, EndListDate) < 42 you mean?

Comment: And depending on how you want to do the counting of days it may even be `< 41`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on @JamieD77's very correct comment...

Your condition:

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR,BeginListDate, EndListDate) >42
```

Says "The number of Years between the `BeginListDate` and the `EndListDate` is greater than 42". That's a hell of a long list period. You say you are looking for the the list period to be less than 42 days, so @JamieD77's suggestion to:

```
Datediff(day,BeginListDate, EndListDate) < 42
```

Is the right way to go. This says "The number of Days between `beginlistdate` and `endlistdate` is less than 42."

The difference here is the `DatePart` as @squillman suggested changing from `Year` to `Day` as well as the inequality itself. You wanted `Less Than`, `<`.

Answer (score 0):

Hint but depended on how would you preferred in report or project.

this example and if both startdate and endate are in the same calendar week, the return value for week would be 0.

select DATEDIFF(week,getdate(),getdate()+7)

it has been consider week start for sunday based on system.